# Better phrase to say "to move to"?

Tags: phrases

I have to insist the readers with an option like this. 
"**If you want to move to online mode, click here to proceed.** "
I am not ok with "to move to"
Is there an alternative phrase which conveys the same meaning with just one "to" or none of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oxford Dictionary:

[**switch** (verb)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/switch) - Adopt (something different) in place of something else; change

'*she worked as a librarian and then switched to journalism.*'

'*But if for any reason he wishes to switch to a different career, he certainly has what it takes in other ways*'

[**activate** (verb)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/activate) - Make (something) active or operative

'*fumes from cooking are enough to activate the alarm.*'

And an example from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/activate): '*Touch the screen to activate the system.*'

So you could say:

*If you want/wish to **switch to**/**activate** online mode, click here*.

or better yet:

*Click here to **switch to**/**activate** online mode.*